# Existe alguma diferença entre os termos rotina e sub-rotina?

Tags: ciência-da-computação

Esses termos seriam intercambiáveis? Ou dentro da programação há diferenças entre os mesmos? Ao meu ver o termo rotina seria algo mais abrangente, que lida com o todo, enquanto sub-rotina seria só uma parte/seção do código/programa.